# When checking if an array is empty, should I use array.length <= 0 or array.length === 0?

Tags: javascript, defensive-programming

I am used to check for empty arrays with `array.length <= 0`. Of course the array should never have a length smaller than 0. This is a habit I developed to make sure my program runs *"just in case something weird happens"*. Is there any reason not to use the `<=` operator and use `=== 0` instead?

Comment: By "list", do you mean "array"?

Comment: Also, you can use just `!list.length`. For empty list, this will return true, else false.

Comment: No need for strict comparison(===), in Javascript Array.length is type of positive number.  So using == is fine. But if your array is undefined then you may end up in error, so it is better to check that also. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `list` is an array, then no, there's no chance of the `length` being anything other than a whole number. From the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-exotic-objects):

> Every Array object has a non-configurable "length" property whose value is always a nonnegative integer less than `2 ** 32`

Given an array object, you couldn't even deliberately make things confusing by changing the `length` to something other than a valid length; an error will be thrown:

```js
const arr = [];
Object.defineProperty(arr, 'length', { value: -5 })
```

Comment: Of course, when you're dealing with proxies or array-likes... But if someone's creating an array proxy that returns a negative number for `length`, or creating an array-like with a negative length, there are other issues... :-)

Answer (score 2):

In my view, there is no reason to check negative value of length `list.length <= 0.`  [as specs for Arrays says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-15.4):

> Every Array object has a length property whose value is always a
>   nonnegative integer less than 2<sup>32</sup>.

So it is perfectly eligible to check `list.length === 0`